# What causes ENOENT errors?

Tags: macos, filesystems, node.js

I am running a Node script and am getting this error at this path:

```
 ENOENT ../../../Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/RunningChromeVersion
```

I can remove the error by closing Chrome.

Most of my Googling has told me that **ENOENT** errors are caused by files/folders that do not exit.

However, in this case the folder clearly exists and has to do with the fact that Chrome is running.

I want to be able to traverse the files even if they are in use.  Is this possible?

Most of the other errors are caused by Apple and I am on an Apple machine.

> ENOENT
>   ../../../Library/Containers/com.apple..NowPlayingWidgetContainer/Data/Documents/iChats

Comment: What function or system call returned this error? Because it's a relative path, what is the *current* path (cwd) of the program at the time of this error?

Comment: What is your concern with the paths?  I am just curious.  I have changed to absolute paths ( from relative ) and am getting the same result.

Answer (score 1):

The item named `RunningChromeVersion` exists, but it is a **symbolic link** whose *target* does not exist. Your Node script doesn't give any special treatment to links, so the default action when trying to open them is to follow the link.

The link's target does not exist because it is not intended to point to a file in the first place. It's a dummy link with some unrelated information (e.g. a version number) stored in the 'target' field where a filename would normally go.

For example, here's the equivalent on Linux (note the `l` "type" indication):

```
$ ls -l ~/.config/chromium
total 4.2M
...
drwx------  3 grawity users 4.0K May 14 09:52 ShaderCache/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 grawity users   20 May 17 13:38 SingletonCookie -> 18396286875963223082
lrwxrwxrwx  1 grawity users   12 May 17 13:38 SingletonLock -> frost-453916
lrwxrwxrwx  1 grawity users   50 May 17 13:38 SingletonSocket -> /tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.7Og2ow/SingletonSocket=
drwx------  3 grawity users 4.0K Dec 27 08:02 SSLErrorAssistant/
...
```

This is a somewhat common method of creating "lock files"; it only takes one syscall to atomically create a link (and fail if it already exists), one syscall to read its "contents" (the 'target' field), and I think it's even NFS/SMB/AFS-compatible whereas actual file locks tend to work less well with these network filesystems.

If you use readdir() to scan directories, then each directory entry already has information about its type: e.g. in Node, you can call [`.isSymbolicLink()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dirent_issymboliclink) on each readdir result.

If you have only the path, you can use the Node equivalent of the [`lstat()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_lstat_path_options_callback) function to check whether a path is a symlink and avoid traversing it that way (there's also `readlink()` to read its 'target' field if you want to).

It is actually *recommended* to skip symlinks when doing recursive file search, because following symlinks might lead you into an infinite loop (e.g. dirA/linkB points to ../dirB, but dirB/linkA points to ../dirA, and now you're stuck).

Comment: I can just do an ls and see a -> which I'm guessing is for the symbolic link.

Comment: what language is lstat()?

Comment: lstat() is a libc function for in C (as such functions are traditionally described), but it's merely an interface to a kernel syscall that's available to all programs – all other languages have interfaces with similar names too. For example, Node provides [fs.lstat()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_lstat_path_options_callback). Additionally, if you use readdir, you don't need to manually stat/lstat each path – you can directly use dirent[.isSymbolicLink()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_dirent_issymboliclink).